# Convert double to date

Tags: r

I have the exchange_rates csv which looks like this:

```
> head(exchange_rates_1)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
      Date USD_by_INR GBP_by_INR EUR_by_INR
     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 20061204       44.6       88.2       59.4

2 20061205       45.1       89.3       60.2

3 20061206       44.7       88.0       59.4

4 20061207       44.7       87.9       59.4

5 20061208       44.7       87.6       59.3

6 20061211       44.8       87.4       59.1
```

And now I want to convert the Date column into real date, like the format "%Y-%M-%D", the  purpose of this operation will be to aggregate it in weeks...

If someone knows a way to aggregate the current Date values in Weeks would be awesome, otherwise if someone knows how to translate the current values into the format described would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We convert the 'Date' to `character` first and then use `as.Date` with `format` as `%Y%m%d`

```
exchange_rate_1$Date <- as.Date(as.character(exchange_rate_1$Date), "%Y%m%d")
```

---

If we need to aggregate by 'week'

```
library(dplyr)
exchange_rate_1 %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(as.character(Date))) %>%
    group_by(YearWeek = format(Date, "%Y %W")) %>%
    summarise(across(ends_with('INR'), ~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: awesome Sir, thank you a lot for the great work!

Answer (score 2):

In response to your **second** question, an easy way is to simply translate the current values into "normal" dates is to use the `lubridate` package.

First, let's put your dates into a vector:

```
dates <- c(20061204, 20061205, 20061206, 20061207, 20061208, 20061211)
> dates
[1] 20061204 20061205 20061206 20061207 20061208 20061211
```

Now, using the `lubridate` package, use the `ymd` function to transform them. `ymd` is used in this case because your data are stored as year-month-date. If your data were organized differently, you could use other configurations

```
dates2 <- lubridate::ymd(dates)
dates2
[1] "2006-12-04" "2006-12-05" "2006-12-06" "2006-12-07" "2006-12-08" "2006-12-11"
```

For more information on `lubridate`, you can check out the website: https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/